# Adobe LiveCycle JavaScript if-else function?

Tags: javascript, scripting, livecycle

I am attempting to do VERY simple code to have a text field have default hints that when moused over, they disappear, and when the mouse leaves, they reeappear. I know I can accomplish this with

```
this.rawValue = "  "
this.rawValue = "Address"
```

with the "Value" section set at default "Address". MY PROBLEM, is that when I type something, if I accidently mouse over the section again, it reverts back to the default value.

What am I missing? I need it to only return to the default value if new text isn't entered.

Comment: Before you mouseover, save the current value of the input in a tmp variable and reset it on mouseleave (note : weird UI)

Comment: I am not sure how to save the value in a tmp variable, any help therE?

Comment: Give me a codepen of your code, I'll show you (I need the rest of your code because there are tens of ways to do that, with or without jQuery ...)

Comment: form1.#subform[0].meetinghouseNameandAddress[0]::mouseExit - (Javascript, client)

Comment: I think that is it. I think I may be in over my head.... all we wanted was text to have a default prepopulated value, then when you type it stays that way or if you dont type, it resets to the default. ;/

Comment: http://codepen.io/topheman/pen/LERNdy here it is, in jQuery. But I wouldn't advise it as UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it so it does not edit the text if the user has entered anything.

in mouseover event:

```
//if the text is the default text, hide it on mouseover.
if (this.rawValue == "Address") this.rawValue = "";
```

in mouseExit event:

```
//if the text is empty, replace it with the default when the user exits the field.
if (this.rawValue == "" || this.rawValue == null) this.rawValue = "Address";
```

I'd consider putting this in normal enter/exit events instead of the mouse-specific ones, because some users may use the tab key to navigate the form.

Also, don't use spaces to signify empty, just use "".

Comment: Thank you. So when I tried to place this in, when you click on the active box, the default goes away and nothing returns if I dont type, and if I do type when I reclick in the box, it resets it to ""  :/

Comment: OKay So I got it to do it, except if I dont type anything it wont return to the default. :/

Comment: All right, there was an issue with the code - extra ) that didn't belong, and had to add the null check as well. I think this should work.

Comment: If this solved it for you, would you please upvote the answer?